# If $U=W_1+W_2$ and $W_1\cap W_2=\{ 0\}$ then $S_1\cap S_2=\emptyset$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that for vector space $U=W_1+W_2$, we have $W_1\cap W_2=\{ 0\}$. How one proves that for a basis $S_1$ of $W_1$ and basis $S_2$ of $W_2$, we have $S_1\cap S_2=\emptyset$.

As a start.. :(

Suppose that $S_1\cap S_2$ isn't empty, therefor exist some vector, say $w\in S_1\cap S_2$ Thus, $w\in S_1$ and $w\in S_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following fact could help us:

> If $U=W_1\oplus W_2$ and $\{w_{11},w_{12},...,w_{1n}\}\in W_1,~~\{w_{21},w_{22},...,w_{2m}\}\in W_2 $ be two independent sets respectively, then the set $\{w_{1i},w_{2j}\}_{i=1..n,j=1..m}$ also be an independent set.

Comment: Is that true: $ \{w_{21},w_{22},...,w_{2m}\} \cap \{w_{11},w_{12},...,w_{1n}\}=\emptyset $ iff  $ \{w_{1i},w_{2j}\}_{i=1..n,j=1..m} $  independent set.
?